# SPeL - set a value of an object which should be in an empty list

Tags: spring, spring-el

I have the following SPel expression:

```
custData.address[0].postcode
```

The `custData` is an existing object but the `address` is an empty list. It is an existing object but it is empty. When I try to set a the post code on this path then I got the

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'postcode' cannot be found on null
```

What I'd need that a new `address` object will be put to the list and set its `postcode` attribute.
Is it something that can be done in the SPel expression?

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ended up using a custom function in spel expression.

```
#addIfNecessary(custData.address, 0, "uk.co.acme.AddressType").postcode
```

The user defined function is

```
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomFunc {

    public static Object addIfNecessary(List<Object> list, Integer index, String className) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Object o = null;
        if (list != null) {
            if (list.size() <= index || list.get(index) == null) {
                list.set(index, Class.forName(className).newInstance());
            }
            o = list.get(index);
        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

It is neither nice nor elegant but it works.
Please let me know if you have a more elegant one!

Answer (score 0):

So this basically is a NullPointerException. You need to make sure the object from which you are trying to get a field value exists. SPeL has the special operator '?' to check if the object has value, though I'm not sure if it works for an array, but definitely worth a try. In general expression where some object might be null looks like this:

```
object?.anotherObject?.field
```

This makes sure that "object" is not null and if it has value gets "anotherObject" and check if it's not null either, and then gets "field". So try something like this:

```
custData.address[0]?.postcode
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am afraid that doesn't work, I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No result type` in this case.

Comment: Maybe you could implement a simple service that will check if this object exists, some method like this: `public boolean checkIfNull( Object object ) { return object == null; }` and then call it in your view in "if-else" clause. I use Thymeleaf as template processor and it looks like this: `<th:block th:unless="${@serviceName.checkIfNull( custData.address[0] )}">[[${custData.address[0].postcode}]]</th:block><th:block th:if="${@serviceName.checkIfNull( custData.address[0] )}">No address object!</th:block>`

Comment: Thanks Pavel! In the end I used the same thinking.